# The derivative of the product of non-commutative functions

Tags: python, sympy, commutativity

If I use functions in SymPy and call the diff method, the commutative property just gets ignored.

```
h = Function('h',real=True,commutative=False)(t)
R = Function('R',real=True,commutative=False)(t)
print(diff(R*h,t))
# returns:
R(t)*Derivative(h(t), t) + h(t)*Derivative(R(t), t)
```

Am I doing something wrong here? I just want the output to have R in the front always..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is arguably a bug in SymPy, which [determines the commutativity of a function from its arguments](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/core/function.py#L576). See also [this comment](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/12945#issuecomment-315642345). It's not related to derivatives: simply printing `h*R` will expose the bug (the expression is presented as `R(t)*h(t)`).

Until this behavior is changed, it seems the only way to achieve the desired result is to declare `t` to be noncommutative:

```
t = Symbol('t', commutative=False)
h = Function('h', real=True)(t)
R = Function('R', real=True)(t)
print(diff(R*h, t))
```

prints

```
R(t)*Derivative(h(t), t) + Derivative(R(t), t)*h(t)
```

Comment: wow, thanks. But yes, I need to make t non-commutative in order to have functions of it not commute?! This is seriously a design decision that lets me doubt.